# Threading an UDP server

Tags: python, multithreading, udp, server

I would like to make a multi-threading UDP server in Python.

The purpose is to be able to connect several clients to the server (not sockets connections but username and password), act with each of them and do some actions on the server. All at the same time.

I am a little confuse with all the different type of threading and I don't know what to use.

To be clearer this is exactly what I want to do at the same time :

- Wait for clients to send data for the first time and register their ip in a database
- Act with "connected" clients by waiting for them to send datagrams and respond to them
- Be able to act with the server. For exemple, change a client's password in my database

Comment: What do you mean by "not sockets connections but username and password"?

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Yeah I think I misspoke. Actually, I know that there is no real connection between UDP sockets. But the first message that a client will send to my server is its username and a password and my server will just verify that it's corresponding to my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a look at a framework that is good at handling asynchronous io. The idea is to not have a thread per socket and block until you receive data, but instead let one thread handle many sockets at once. This scales well if you want your server to handle many clients.

For example:

- [Gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) - "a coroutine-based Python networking library", [example](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/examples/udp_server.py)
- [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) - "an event-driven networking engine", [example](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/udp.html)
- [Eventlet](http://eventlet.net/) - "a concurrent networking library", [example](http://eventlet.net/doc/examples.html#socket-connect) (TCP, but  it uses a patched [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) so you can also refer to the Python wiki page about [UDP Communication](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication))

Comment: Yes it's almost the purpose.

To be clearer this is exactly what I want to do at the same time :

- Wait for clients to send data for the first time and register their ip in a database

- Act with "connected" clients by waiting for them to send datagrams and respond to them

- Be able to act with the server. For exemple, change a client's password in my database

Comment: I wrote a sample UDP chat client/server using gevent. Nothing fancy and probably full of bugs, but it might give you some ideas: https://github.com/andrelaszlo/gevent-chat